# Prevent Google Maps zooming when Double click or Pinch on Linear layout which is placed below the map fragment

Tags: android

how to stop map zooming when I pinch on linear layout which is placed bottom of our map fragment..please can any one help me..

This is my code to catch single and Double click events

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

            Log.d("on dispatchTouchEvent ", " dispatchTouchEvent ");
            switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {




                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    fingers = fingers + 1;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                    fingers = fingers - 1;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    fingers = 0;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    if (firstClick != 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - firstClick > 300) {
                        Log.w("on count=0", " count=0 ");
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        Log.w("on count ", " count=1 ");
                        firstClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else if (count == 2) {
                        Log.w("on count ", " count=2 ");
                        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (lastClick - firstClick < 300) {

                            CameraUpdate getzoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn();
                            mMap.animateCamera(getzoom, 400, null);
                            Log.w("on double click ", " event ");
                        }

                    }


                    fingers=1;
                    break;
            }

            if (fingers >1) {

                Log.d("2fingersaction ", "2fingersaction ");
                mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                // mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);         // disableScrolling()
            }
            else if (fingers < 1 )
            {
                Log.d("onefinger ", "onefinger ");
                mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

                mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                // enableScrolling();
            }
}
```

I placed this code out side of `OnMapReady()` Method ..

here is the screenshot of my app..[image] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

``finally i got the Answer..

First of all we need to activate touch events only on mapfragment by getting Xpoint and Ypoint..

and check the condition of touch event in dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev), ,method...make sure that if we touch on mapfragment then only we need to activate Touch action or pinch action...

```
enter code here
```

Comment: boolean isWithinMapBounds(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
  int[] l = new int[2];
  View mapView = mapFragment.getView();
  mapView.getLocationOnScreen(l);
  int x = l[0];
  int y = l[1];
  int w = mapView.getWidth();
  int h = mapView.getHeight();

  if (xPoint< x || xPoint> x + w || yPoint< y || yPoint> y + h) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }

Comment: place this in Dispatch touch event method                                                                      public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

  if (!isWithinMapBounds(ev.getRawX(),ev.getRawY())){
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in my app and turns out the answer was pretty simple.

In your linear layout set the following property to true:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Now what this does is makes your layout intercept the touch event and doesn't let it go to the map. Therefore it works for all gestures and touch events..

Hope this helps..

Cheers :D

Comment: Sorry Brother @Arjun it is not working...I need to stop zooming when i touch outside of Map Fragment...